# explain this javascript function declaration "jQuery(function($){}"

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

i came across this piece of script in the source code of a chrome extension. it declares a function:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#actionCopy').click(function(e){
        Action.copy();
    });
});
```

what is that `jQuery` word used at the beginning of the function? and what does the dollar sign that is used as the function argument do? (  function(`$`)  )

Comment: And you didn't even tag this with jQuery *sigh*. Anyway the most complete answer will be found on [this link](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3

Comment: *"what is that jQuery word used at the beginning of the function?"* Well, it's the name of a function being invoked `jQuery(/**args**/)` just like you'd expect for any other function. The argument passed to the `jQuery()` function just happens to be another function. Functions are objects and can be passed around just like any other data.

Comment: ...in a similar manner, the `$` is a parameter to the function argument. When invoked it is passed a value. That value is a function. The function argument passed to `$` just so happens to be the same `jQuery` function, so now you have two different references to the same function. `jQuery === $; // true`

Comment: is it the same as this?   `(function($){ //code })(jQuery);`

Comment: @burhan: No, in the first case you are calling `jQuery`, in the second case you are calling a function you just defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what is that jQuery word used at the beginning of the function?

It refers to a function called `jQuery` (defined by the library available from [http://jquery.com](http://jquery.com/)).

That particular function is horribly overloaded, but in this case (when it receives one argument that is a function) it means "Bind this function to the document ready event" (with some pollyfill for the benefit of browsers that don't support that event natively).

> and what does the dollar sign that is used as the function argument do?

The same as a letter `a` or the word `foo` or anything else. It defines the variable name that the argument will be passed to. There is nothing special about the `$` character in JavaScript variable names.

Answer (score 3):

Passing in a *function* as first argument into the *jQuery constructor function* is just a shortcut for `.ready()`.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
});
```

jQuery will be kind enough to pass in the `jQuery` *object reference* into the callback which you pass in for the `.ready` handler. That means, you can just savely access the *jQuery object* using the dollar sign `$` within.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is popular javascript library. $ is the shorthand for accessing jQuery object. Passing $ in function 'function($)' will make sure that $ will not be conflicted with any other javascript library used.